# When I load a file into a div, the div jumps down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="pollid" >
<select class="pollid" id="pollid" size="[2]" >
 [options]
</select></div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<div class="options">
<select class="options" id="options" disabled="disabled" size="2">
<option id="deadoption">Select a poll to enable this box.</option>
</select></div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
<div class="options2" id="options2">
</div>
</body>
```

I also have a bit of jquery that just does this when a specific option in the second div is selected:

```
$("#options2").load("ajax/newOption.html");
```

And newOption.html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="newopt" label="Option: " />
<button id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

The CSS I have looks like this:

```
select {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

div.pollid  {
height: 100%;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
}

div.options {
height: 100%;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
}

div.options2 {
height: 100%;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
}

.seperator {
height: 100%;
width: 3%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Now, this works. However, when I click the option that loads that page, the div jumps down so that the bottom of the input is at the bottom of my screen. This is not what I want. I want the div to stay where it is, taking up 30% of the screen. I don't want the screen to scroll at all, which it does once the html is loaded. How might I be able to fix this?

Comment: mmm I think that is breaking your HTML, check it with the console

Comment: What happens when you manually insert the HTML code inside the div and load the page? How does it looks like?

Comment: When I manually insert it into the div, the same thing happens. If I copy one of the select elements from an above div into it, then it works properly, but if I put anything else inside it it still jumps down to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Actually, if I insert any select element with a size specified it works the same as the other selects. But I don't know why.

Comment: why do you use AJAX to load newOption.html?  If it is just two lines and always the same, you could just embed them in the div, and `hide()` when the page loads.  Then, the same event that triggers your Ajax could just `show()` these two lines.  It would load a lot faster.

Comment: There are two things it could show and one does need AJAX, so it's easier to have it load both. Either way, this happens. Like I said, even if I just paste it into the page, save it, and refresh, the div is still shifted down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after experimenting. It looks like, for some reason, putting anything in any of these divs other than the `<select size="x>1">` makes it jump down, and giving them the property `vertical-align:top` fixes that.